# Vuetify v-tabs switching tabs long time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I have 2 v-tab in which the data is updated dynamically. Sometimes if a huge data comes switching between the tabs takes a long time. In each tab, I will be creating input fields, text areas based on the response. So if response is so huge I need to create many fields which is taking long time to render. Is there a way to optimize this, I tried to keep a loader when switching the tabs, but don't know when the dom will get loaded completed. Is there a life cycle event to handle it in vue? I tried updated() event with "nextTick" but it is called before the render.

Comment: Are you familiar with <keep-alive>? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components Maybe that could resolve your problem

Comment: @DimaVak.Cache will work only after the elements get loaded right? correct me if I am wrong. In my case when I am loading it for the first time itself it takes 5 to 6 seconds. Also, I kept the block inside <keep-alive> but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I think you should keep the content of each tab item inside its own `<keep-alive>` - thus for 2 tabs you will need 2 `<keep-alive>` blocks.

Comment: Have you figured out the way to solve this issue ?